# При записи переменной в файл интерпритатор выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, type-error, текстовые-файлы

```
v = open(u"/storage/emulated/0/PyTycoon/Variables.txt","w")
#Variables
l = 1
k = 0
s1 = 5
money = 0
#Commands
while True:
    z = input()
    if z == ".":
        money = money + 1
    elif z == "balance" or z == "b":
        print(f"balance: {money}")
    elif z == "shop" or z == "sh":
        print(f"------Shop------\nshovel(+5) - {s1}$")
    elif z == "buy shovel":
        money = money - s1
        l = l + 5
        print(f"balance: {money}")
    elif z == "save" or "s":
        v.write(money)
```

Суть работы:

Когда пишешь точку, в переменную `money` добавляется единица. Когда пишешь **save**, в текстовый файл должна записаться переменная.

Проблема:

Когда пытаюсь сохранить переменную файл выдает ошибку **TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int**

Comment: Что вам непонятно в ошибке "аргумент `write()` должен быть строкой, а не числом"? :)  Ну, сделайте строку через `str(money)` или `f{money}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно в ошибке всё и написано, записывать нужно `str`, a `money` у вас `int`
Поэтому в последней строчке замените `v.write(money)` на `v.write(str(money))`

Comment: спасибо, просто я новичок в этом